# Make zeros to certain rows in 2D array

Tags: swift

Is there a way to make these loops in one line of code or shorter form?

```
var matrix : [[Int]] = [
  [0,1,2,9],
  [3,4,5,2],
  [1,3,1,5]
]

for i in rowIndexes
{ 
  for c in 0..<nCol
  {
      matrix[i][c] = 0
  }
}

output : [[Int]] = [
  [0,0,0,0],
  [3,4,5,2],
  [1,3,1,5]
 ]
```

Comment: How do you want it to look like after?

Comment: I believe there should be shorter form of my approach such as functional programming